# Prove the existence of the derivatives of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

Problem:
Consider the function $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$ when $x\neq0$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$.

I have proved $f'$ exist by Newton Quotient, and the problem asks to prove the existence of further derivatives fo $f(x)$.

I am not sure where to start. I tried to prove this by induction with Newton Quotient, but I cannot find a general form of $f^n(x)$.

A solution was given but I don't really understand:

> We can see that $f^{(n)} (x)$ will contain a term proportional to $x^{−3n}e^{−1/x^2}$ along with smaller inverse powers of $x$ (the $x^{−3n}$ is the most singular as $x \to 0$). Since
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{−1/x^2}}{x^{3n}}= 0,$$
> we also define $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ and hence all higher derivatives exist.

I don't really understand what "most singular" mean in here. Also, how is the limit of $f'$  and $f^n$ equals to 0 related with the existence of derivative?

Comment: Try writing the first few terms of the exponential function, and you'll see how rapidly the fraction diminishes.  $1/x^n$ is singular as there's a hole at zero.  It can be removed by multiplying "some $x$'s".  The greater the $n$, the "more" $x$'s you need, so the "harder" to remove this singularity.

Comment: It's easier to use the product rule to calculate a few successive derivatives and convince yourself that the pattern is as described.  Write the formula as $e^{-x^{-2}}$ and use the chain rule for the first derivative. Then the second and higher derivatives can be calculated from the first derivative you just calculated and successive derivatives of $x^{-n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider functions of the form
$$\tag1g(x)=\begin{cases}p(x^{-1})e^{-\frac1{x^2}}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases} $$
where $p$ is a polynomial.

Prove that $g$ is

- continuous also at $x=0$,
- differentable at $x\ne 0$,
- also differentiable at $x=0$ with $g'(0)=0$

and conclude that $g'$ is also of the form $(1)$.

Now as $f=f^{(0)}$ is of form $(1)$ with $p$ constant, conclude by induction that $f^{(n)}$ is of that form for all $n$.

Comment: Should $g(x)=pe^{-1/x^2}$ if $x\neq 0$? Since $f^{(0)}$ does not have $x^{-1}$.